# R: write a two stage function which returns a vector

Tags: r, function

[image: values of d_j's. j ranges from 0 to m-2]

I want to use R to write a function f(m,r) where m,r are integers such that m>r>=1 and f returns a vector of d_j's. I'm a beginner to R and I guess I may need loop in the function body. But how to write it exactly? Thanks in advance.

The picture shows values of d_j's and j ranges from 0 to m-2.

Answer (score 1):

In step 2, you're assigning a new value to dj. I can't think why and how step 1 could be a necessary prerequisite for step 2.

Below are two different functions, f1() and f2(). The idea is to recode "for 0 <= j <= r - 1" into a range that you can iterate over:

```
f1 <- function(m, r) {
    if (m <= r) {stop('m <= r')}
    if (r <= 1) {stop('r <= 1')}
    d <- c()
    for (j in 0 : r - 1) {d <- c(d, (m - r) * (j + 1))}
    return(d)
}
f2 <- function(m, r){
    if (m <= r) {stop('m <= r')}
    if (r <= 1) {stop('r <= 1')}
    d <- c()
    for (j in r : m - 1) {d <- c(d, r*(m - j - 1))}
    return(d)
}
f1(12, 4)
#[1]  0  8 16 24 32
f2(12, 4)
#[1] 32 28 24 20 16 12  8  4  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The operations you are applying do not depend on one another for the different inputs; that is, computing d_1 won't influence or be influenced by d_2, d_3, etc.  Usually when this is the case, you can use R's vectorized operations (or one of the `apply` family of functions) to avoid formally writing `for` loops.

In the following function definition I wrote the vectors `0:(r-1)` and `r:(m-1)` as the vector of `j` values to be input to each formula.

```
d_j <- function(m,r) {
  a1 <- (m-r) * ((0:(r-1)) + 1)
  a2 <- r * (m - 1 - (r:(m-1)))
  return(c(a1,a2))
}
```

Let's test a simple case.  For `m=3`, `r=1` we should return `2` from the first formula and `c(1,0)` from the second formula:

```
> d_j(3,1)
[1] 2 1 0
```

For a larger case we have

```
> d_j(12,4)
 [1]  8 16 24 32 28 24 20 16 12  8  4  0
```